# if a .net app is on amazon ec2, is the instance always running

Tags: amazon-ec2

little confused as to how the instances work.
if I run a windows server instance, and say nobody hits the website, is the instance still running on their end or does it shutdown ever

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the instance is always running. It's just like a normal server and it doesn't matter if it's working or just idling.

Comment: so idling is free?

Comment: No, you're paying not for the CPU time, but the time the server is running. So only when you shut down the server it stops costing you money.